# correct syntax for docker file alpine with --platform and php fpm-alpine

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, fpm

What is the correct syntax to add a PHP version in docker file?

i have this syntax:

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86-64 alpine:3.11 php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime && \
    echo "UTC" | tee /etc/timezone && \
    apk del tzdata

RUN apk --update add wget \
    curl \
    git \
    php7 \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlreader \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-pcntl \
    php7-json \
    php7-dom \
    php7-zip \
    php7-gd \
    php7-curl \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-redis \
    php7-posix \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-phar \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-sockets \
    php7-fileinfo && rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

The problem with this syntax is I am getting an error on this line:
`FROM --platform=linux/x86-64 alpine:3.11 php:7.4-fpm-alpine`

What is the correct syntax to add a PHP version in my docker file?

Thanks!

Comment: do you need all of it? I am pretty sure `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` should be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` only accepts one *or* three arguments and `--platform=linux/x86_64` is a modifier not an argument so split it onto two lines.

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 alpine:3.11
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
```

Although, according to the [Official Docs](https://prototype.php.net/versions/7.4/install/docker), you probably only want `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` unless you have another reason for wanting things that are available on the `alpine:3.11` image that are not on the `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` image.

Adding my changes to the your `Dockerfile` results in the below. I have tested this and `docker build ./` works with this file in an empty directory.

```
 FROM --platform=linux/x86-64 alpine:3.11 
 FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
 
 WORKDIR /app
 
 ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
 ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
 
 RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata && \
     cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime && \
     echo "UTC" | tee /etc/timezone && \
     apk del tzdata
 
 RUN apk --update add wget \
     curl \
     git \
     php7 \
     php7-opcache \
     php7-ctype \
     php7-xml \
     php7-xmlreader \
     php7-xmlwriter \
     php7-tokenizer \
     php7-pcntl \
     php7-json \
     php7-dom \
     php7-zip \
     php7-gd \
     php7-curl \
     php7-mbstring \
     php7-redis \
     php7-posix \
     php7-mcrypt \
     php7-iconv \
     php7-pdo_mysql \
     php7-phar \
     php7-simplexml \
     php7-openssl \
     php7-sockets \
     php7-fileinfo && rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

As an additional recommendation, and this is more a "consistency" thing than a "your build will break soon" because PHP 7.4 is in LTS and there will be no PHP 7.5. You may want to change `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` to `FROM php:7-fpm-alpine` as you're intstalling `php7-*` packages which will *technically* take the latest compatible version 7 package but your locking your `php-fpm` version to the latest 7.*4* version.